# Drupal: Issue in DruTex

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, latex, drupal-modules

I have installed and configured DruTex (in my Drupal6 installation).

But when I go to create a page, a warning appears on the top of the page as:

> warning: Parameter 1 to drutex_pdf_nodeapi() expected to be a reference, value given in /usr/share/drupal6/modules/drutex/drutex.module on line 829.

Please help me in removing it.

Note: I used a `@` in the mentioned file on line 829 however then following errors come when I create a page :

```
TeX Embedding failed!
```

Comment: `@`s are special. Although I haven't worked with DruTeX, what about surround `@`-usage with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`?

Comment: What's actually in `/usr/share/drupal6/modules/drutex/drutex.module` on either side an including line 829?